# Проблема с запуском Vesta Control Panel в virtualbox на ubuntu-16.04 и на cent os 7 "страница не найдена"

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, centos, virtualbox

Хочу запустить виртуальный сервер, поставил ubuntu-16.04 и cent os 7,

Скачал и туда и туда Vesta Control Panel,

Установка прошла успешно без ошибок в конце ip адрес логин пароль. Попробовал открыть страницу по указанному ip, но "страница не найдена".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите в чем дело как запустить Vesta Control Panel, какие еще действия нужно сделать? Нигде не находил решения.

при установке Vesta задается тестовый сайт
так вот он у меня открыл когда я задал его в файле hosts, прописал ip своего виртуального сервера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

команда ping 188.186.234.234 выдает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы сделали 2 разные виртуальные машины? как настроена сеть для них? какой тип адаптера выбран? какой ip вам выдал установщик?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman устанавливал оси по очереди, выбран тип подключения сетевой мост, далее выбрал мой сетевой адаптер realteck, скачивание и установка Vesta прошло успешно. Дополнил вопрос. может быть думаю ip стартовой страницы тоже нужно как то прописать?

Comment: а почему вы используете протокол https? и что это за ip?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman следовал этой инструкции http://linux-notes.org/ustanovka-vestacp-na-centos/

этот адрес генерирует панель после завершения установки

Comment: эта инструкция не для ВМ. что выдает команда `ping 188.186.234.234` запущенная на хосте?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил к вопросу. Но сама панель точно скачалась в окне целых 10 минут ползли какие то строки а по завершении мне выдался ip логин пароль и тестовый сайт заработал когда я указал ip сервера в файле hosts, вот только как заставить работать панель не знаю

Answer (score 0):

для того чтобы подключиться к панели нужно вводить не ip который был указан при установке а собственный `ip`
В моем случае это так

```
https://192.168.0.119:8083
```